# How can I make iOS stop switching away from my internal network?

Tags: ios, wifi

My iOS app needs to run on infrastructure networks that are not connected to the internet. But the device seems to always automatically switch to a previously-used available network that has internet connectivity. What am I doing that might be permitting/requesting this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior of the OS. If you do not want to reconnect to a previously used wifi network: go to the settings app -> wifi -> select the wifi the device keeps connecting to -> forget this network

Comment: Ouch. I don't really want my user to have to delete their "real" network just to switch to the other one temporarily so the app can talk to my embedded devices on it. Any idea how it determines that a network is not on the internet, and is that a test that my embedded device can fool with the right responses?